# Getting a strange corruption of a string returned by a handleMessage in a class that extends Handler

Tags: android, string, message, android-handler, corruption

I have an android class that extends Handler and is receiving a string from a Bluetooth stream.  Somewhere along the string, the characters are overwritten and the string extended.  Here's an example string:

Day 1 @ 11:10am:  Closed,  Open @ 2:00am, Close @ android.widget.EditText{4bc3048 V.ED..CL. ........ 0,.

Here's some code:

```
    @Override
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        DeviceControlActivity activity = mActivity.get ();
        if (activity != null) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    Utils.log ("MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:" + msg.arg1);
                    final ActionBar bar = activity.getActionBar ();
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case DeviceConnector.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            if(bar.getSubtitle() != MSG_CONNECTED) {
                                activity.BeeSeekStop();
                            }
                            bar.setSubtitle (MSG_CONNECTED);
                            break;
                        case DeviceConnector.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            bar.setSubtitle (MSG_CONNECTING);
                            break;
                        case DeviceConnector.STATE_NONE:
                            if(bar.getSubtitle() == MSG_NOT_CONNECTED) {
                                activity.BeeSeekStart();
                            }
                            bar.setSubtitle (MSG_NOT_CONNECTED);
                            break;
                    }
                    activity.invalidateOptionsMenu ();
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    final String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    ...
                    break;
```

I'd expect to see:

Day 1 @ 11:10am:  Closed,  Open @ 2:00am, Close @ 3:00am.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like android.widget.EditText{4bc3048 V.ED..CL. ........ 0,. is actually edittext ID because you may be trying to get text like this : `edittext.getText()` and not casting it to string.
You have to do it like this : edittext.getText().toString();

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've checked all of my uses of getText() and I'm always suffixing them with a toString(), so if I understand you correctly, I'm doing it like you say.  The problem shows in the msg variable itself.

Comment: I have just double checked it. Sorry to mention toString() wrongly, actually you are not calling edittext.getText.toString() but you are calling edittext.toString(). Let me know after double checking it. Becuase I got android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{fa88f2b VFED..CL. ........ 42,383-1038,500 #7f0900d3 app:id/edtx_email} when called edittext.toString().

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The string that is transmitted via Bluetooth is as shown at the bottom of my question. I never use any <EditText instance>.toString() at all. I am using EditText widgets in my XML. Those are cast as TextViews to which I apply .getText().toString(). But those, as far as I can tell, don't even come into play at that point, being set later in my code. Maybe I'm missing something. Are you perhaps drawing too much significance to the string that is corrupting the Bluetooth stream string?  I assume that's just a random grab from memory that just happens to say EditText.

Comment: Your comment:   "Becuase I got android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{fa88f2b VFED..CL. ........ 42,383-1038,500 #7f0900d3 app:id/edtx_email} when called edittext.toString()." intrigues me though.  Maybe my understanding of the situation is primitive.  Hope to hear more about your reasoning, Faisal.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's all Faisal has to say.  Does anyone else know what he's talking about?